# How to work with user's text entry in an HTA form

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have the a button on my hta file that when i click on will trigger a batch file to run.  I want user to input the computer name into a text box and use it at the below psexec command which requires the computer name.  Any recommendations would greatly appreciated.

```
<script language="VBScript">
Sub InstallVNC
    dim shell
    set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
    shell.run "psexec -u domain01\username -p password \\textbox1.value -c \\doamin\SHARE\SOFTWARE\install_program.bat"
End Sub


<body bgcolor="buttonface">
<p><font face="verdana" color="red">Application Installer</font></p>
Please run as administrator. <p>
<form name="test">
<font>Computer Name:</font>
<input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1">
</form>
<input id=runbutton  class="button" type="button" value="Install VNC" name="db_button"  onClick="installvnc"><p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the input string differently.  Something like this:

```
Sub InstallVNC
  dim shell
  dim strInput
  dim shell_parameter
  strInput = textbox1.value
  shell_parameter = "psexec -u domain01\username -p password \\" & strInput  & " -c   \\doamin\SHARE\SOFTWARE\install_program.bat"
  set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
  shell.run shell_parameter
End Sub
```

About getting the user input:  I haven't used `<form>` in hta -- a dialog box has always been simpler.  I wonder if that would get you past the problem.  This code would be invoked when the button is pressed:

```
Dim strDialogPrompt, strDialogTitle, strDialogDefault

strDialogTitle = "File location"

strDialogPrompt = "Enter location of file to install." _
    & vbCrLf & "(You must run this as Administrator.)"

strDialogDefault = "Z:\The_Usual_Path"

strInput = InputBox(strDialogPrompt, strDialogTitle, strDialogDefault, 150, 150)
```

Comment: Still giving me an error message.  Says Object required 'textbox1', code 0

Comment: I guess it's lazy, but I'm adding a suggestion to my answer: skip the `<form>` and `<input>` tags, go simple with a dialog box.

Comment: @user2651624 Code works for me. Does your input field actually have the ID "textbox1"?

Comment: Sorry.  It actually worked.  He is right.  I took out the <form> and it worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basic DOM manipulation:

```
Dim computerName
computerName = document.getElementById("textbox1").value
```

For more information, you can consult pretty much any DOM reference (e.g., https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM)

Comment: In HTAs you can access elements with just their ID, so `textbox1.value` should work fine if the element actually does have the ID "textbox1".

Comment: Agree.  There prolly aren't many people who use both HTA and the `document` object.